# Set first option selected in dropdown list and get value?

Tags: angular

I want on load to set select first option in dropdown and then get that value and do something with it. I tried this:

```
<select class="form-control custom-select" type="text" [(ngModel)]="model" (change)="changeVertical(model)">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option *ngFor="let vertical of ls.registries['verticals'],  let i = index" [(value)]="vertical.code"
                    [attr.selected]='i==1 ? "selected" : null'>
                    {{vertical.name}}</option>
</select>



changeVertical(model) {
        this.changeCategory.emit(model);
    }
```

But this is not working, it only work if i set `i>0` but then it set last element and i dont want to do that. And other thing is that i can not get value because it never enter in this `changeVertical` method. I tried to get value on `ngOnChanges` but its same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular automatically selects the entry, which is bound by ngModel. All you need to do is to set `ls.registries['verticals'][0].code` to `model` in your ts file.

**html**

```
<select class="form-control custom-select" type="text" [(ngModel)]="model" (change)="changeVertical(model)">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option *ngFor="let vertical of ls.registries['verticals']" [value]="vertical.code">
    {{vertical.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

**ts**

```
this.model = this.ls.registries['verticals'][0].code;
```

PS.: I recommend to rename `model` to `selectedCode`